# How to create an oriented window arround a pixel in an image using MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, window

I am trying to extract an oriented window of size 15x15(say), around a pixel in an image. The orientation can be of any angle or say step of 15 degrees.

I have tried some logic but did not give satisfactory result, i.e. if I see the oriented Window using imshow(), the window is rotated but the image has some swirl effects.

```
b=15; % Window Size 
rm = [cos(rad2deg(theta)) -sin(rad2deg(theta)); sin(rad2deg(theta)) cos(rad2deg(theta))];
Lx=-floor(b/2):floor(b/2);
Ly=-floor(b/2):floor(b/2);
block=zeros(b,b);

for i=1:length(Lx)
    for j=1:length(Ly)
        [T]=rm*[Lx(i) Ly(j)]';
        tx=round(T(1)+x);
        ty=round(T(2)+y);
        block(i,j)=im(tx,ty);
    end
end
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `rad2deg` and then `sin`, `cos`. The `sin`, `cos` functions expect their input in radians

Comment: Thanks @LuisMendo for your comment. Could you please suggest some corrections need in the above code for the desired result.